# How to mock a class in my exception class?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have to access ApplicationContext in MyException class

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(Map<String, Map<String,String>> errorObj) throws IOException {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
            Environment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
            ...
    }
}
```

And this service throw it.

```
 @Service
 public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    public Response myFunction() {

          throw new MyException(errorObj);
       ...
    }
 }
```

Edit this is ApplicationContextProvider

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

when I run unittest I got NullPointerException on ApplicationContext. I want to mock ApplicationContext How to do this?

I found this error only unit testing but when I run with spring-boot:run it work fine

Comment: what is ApplicationContextProvider ?

Comment: I already add more detail

Comment: I guess ApplicationContextProvider  is a spring bean(It has one of the spring annotation) but MyException is not a bean. So you cannot autowire it in MyException Class. Also since application context is not loaded in your test class, getApplicationContext method returns null. Another problem u have is since getApplicationContext is a static method, you cannot mock it using mockito, you need to use powermockito for that

Comment: Yes I know I can use @autowire only inside spring container class but I get bean outside spring container by ApplicationContextProvider class it work fine when I run spring-boot:run

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to have access to the application context and the Environment from the Exception?

Comment: @Wim Deblauwe This is existing code that too old and it use for getting some property.It shouldn't use Environment from the Exception right? I can change this code.

Comment: And what do you do based on that property value in the exception?

Comment: @Wim Deblauwe the value is firebase url for look up error code and error description that It can change everytime

Comment: In that case, it will probably be easier to have a Spring managed `@Component` class that you give the exception to and will reach out to Firebase when something in your application actually needs that information. This way, you can directly inject the `Environment`, or use `@ConfigurationProperties`. Doing a call to Firebase in the constructor of an Exception seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) annotation in test class which create an application contect containning all the objects required for test.

Comment: do you have an example?